# Modal show wrong result

Tags: php

The result of my code is as follows (top ten country):

```
Country1 24
Country2 18
Country3 15
Country4 11
Country5 10
Country6 9
Country7 9
Country8 5
Country9 2
Country10 1
```

When I click countryN, I want to display a modal that contains the IP addresses of clicked country.

```
<?php
$black="SELECT country,count(country) as number from bl where country!='NULL' group by country order by number desc limit 10";
$sql=mysql_query($black);
?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
<?php
if (mysql_num_rows($sql)!=0)
{
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo ("<tr>");
        echo ("<td><div align=\"center\"><a href='#openModal' name='modal'><img name='img' src=../Include/flag/".strtolower($result["country"]).".gif></a></div></td>");
        echo("<td ><span class='badge'>".$result["number"]."</span></td>");
        echo ("</tr>");
        if (modal==true)
        {
            $bl="SELECT * from bl where country='".$result['country']."'";
            $bl_res=mysql_query($bl);
            ?>

            <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
                <div>
                    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                    <h2>Blacklist details</h2>
                    <?php
            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($bl_res))
            {
                echo $row['timestamp']." ".$row['ip']." ".$row['sensor']."<br>";
            }
            ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is that when I click on any country, it shows me the IP addresses of the country1.

Comment: `mysql_*` is **Evil** !

Comment: Show us where you get the country param

Comment: pls show us html as well and jQuery/javascript

Comment: what is the $sql variable? do you select all rows from database? or how is the query built up

Comment: You're exposed to SQL injection in this way `"SELECT * from bl where country='".$result['country']."'"`. Take a look at http://it1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php or http://it1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I guess that this line `modal==true` should be `$modal==true` or something?

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_fetch_array` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: I updated my code. But I think the problem is in the name of modal ... it should be modal1, modal2 ... ?!